# Html input value in server side code. Asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="Server">  
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
                $("#slider-range").slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    values: [0, 75],
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#value").val("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
                    }
                });
                $("#value").val("" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
                " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
            });
  </script>
</asp:content>
```

I am using this code for a slider in my asp.net page. Now the value in displayed in the Html input.

```
  <input type="text" id="value" style="border: 0; font-weight: bold;" />
```

it is displayed as 0-75. How can I get both the values (0,75) separately in my server side so that i can write the values in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure there is enough information here, but making a bunch of assumptions.

```
<input type="text" id="value" name="value" style="border: 0; font-weight: bold;" />
```

Then when you submit your page:

```
Request.Form["value"] (OR Request.QueryString["value"] in some cases)
```

... will contain your value.

```
string[] values;
string value = Request.Form["value"];
if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( value ) )
{
    values = value.Split( '-' );
}
```

Comment: I am using a master page, how to get values from there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a form element, these value would be available in the form collection and in the button click event you can check `Request.Form["value"].ToString()` and should be able to get the value as *0-75* which you can then split